# CSS doesn't override previews call css | antD react

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am working on Tables using antD. By default, whenever you hover a Table Row in antD it gets a slight gray color transition as a highlight. I wish to change the color. I did this using `less`:

```
.ant-table-row {
    &:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

(NOTE: the actual color doesn't matter. it's just an example)

Whenever hovering the Row, it becomes Blue, as set, for a slight second and then becomes light gray again...

Checking the element CSS, via chrome tools, there is NO other `:hover` CSS for that object other than the blue color I added. Yet for some reason, this doesn't work...

In addition, tried using `rowClassName` to give a custom class and using it with the `&:hover` with the same results.

Here's a gif that shows the issue in action [image: antD table row hover effect issue]

Also a working example (online): **https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cache-w22lg?file=/src/App.js**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace with the following:

```css
.ant-table-row:hover td{
  background-color: blue!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here two think

1. put your custom style file below all style file
2. add !important link below

   .ant-table-row { &:hover {  background-color: blue !important ; } }

Comment: Tried it - same result. Also, i updated the post including the demo.